# How to upload folder with subfolder to amazon s3?

Tags: java, amazon-s3, file-upload

I need upload folder with subfolders on amazon s3. I try upload with this snipet.

```
    for (Path path : directoryWalk("/home/rmuhamedgaliev/tmp/eota7tas0cdlg2ufq5mlke7olf/")){
       if (!path.getParent().toString().equals("eota7tas0cdlg2ufq5mlke7olf")){
        amazonS3Client.putObject("*****", "/plans/eota7tas0cdlg2ufq5mlke7olf/" + path.getParent().toString() + "/" + path.getFileName(), new File(path.toString()));
       } else {
        amazonS3Client.putObject("*******", "/plans/eota7tas0cdlg2ufq5mlke7olf/" + path.getFileName(), new File(path.toString()));
       }
    }
```

But this code create full path files with **("/home/rmuhamedgaliev/tmp/eota7tas0cdlg2ufq5mlke7olf")**. How to upload it with path **("/plans/eota7tas0cdlg2ufq5mlke7olf/{subfolders and files}")**

```
    private List<Path> directoryWalk(String path) throws IOException {
        final List<Path> files = new ArrayList<>();
        Files.walkFileTree(Paths.get(path), new SimpleFileVisitor<Path>() {

            @Override
            public FileVisitResult visitFile(Path file, BasicFileAttributes attrs) throws IOException {
                files.add(file);
                return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
            }
        });
        return files;
    }
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Have you looked at the `TransferManager` in the AWS SDK for Java?  You could use the `uploadDirectory` method for this.  The javadoc is [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/s3/transfer/TransferManager.html#uploadDirectory%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.io.File,%20boolean%29).  In essence, you could do something like this:

```
transferManager.uploadDirectory(bucketName, "plans/eota7tas0cdlg2ufq5mlke7olf/", new File("/home/rmuhamedgaliev/tmp/eota7tas0cdlg2ufq5mlke7olf/"), true);
```

Comment: The suggested way to get TransferManger is by using  TransferManagerBuilder.defaultTransferManager()

Answer (score 1):

I writen my own way.

```
        List<File> files = new LinkedList<File>();
        listFiles(new File("/home/rmuhamedgaliev/tmp/eota7tas0cdlg2ufq5mlke7olf"), files, true);
        for (File f : files) {
            String key = f.getAbsolutePath().substring(new File("/home/rmuhamedgaliev/tmp/eota7tas0cdlg2ufq5mlke7olf").getAbsolutePath().length() + 1)
                .replaceAll("\\\\", "/");
            amazonS3Client.putObject("****", "plans/eota7tas0cdlg2ufq5mlke7olf/" + key, f);
        }
```

Comment: I want to upload all files which are present in single folder such as suppose I have folder name "TestMech" which contains number of photos that all photo i need to upload with the help of progress indicator is it possible & how